# Problems when make bochs on Mac OS X mountain lion

Tags: macos, bochs

I have installed the X11 on Mac:

when I input some codes in terminal:

*./configure --with-x11*

*make*

After that, there appears some problems:

```
x.cc:37:22: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
x.cc:38:23: error: X11/Xutil.h: No such file or directory
x.cc:39:21: error: X11/Xos.h: No such file or directory
x.cc:40:23: error: X11/Xatom.h: No such file or directory
x.cc:41:24: error: X11/keysym.h: No such file or directory
x.cc:42:35: error: X11/extensions/Xrandr.h: No such file or directory
x.cc:86: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
x.cc:88: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
x.cc:89: error: ‘Colormap’ does not name a type
x.cc:104: error: ‘Window’ does not name a type
x.cc:105: error: ‘GC’ does not name a type
x.cc:108: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
x.cc:136: error: ‘Pixmap’ does not name a type
x.cc:140: error: ‘Pixmap’ does not name a type
x.cc:146: error: ‘Pixmap’ does not name a type
x.cc:304: error: variable or field ‘xkeypress’ declared void
x.cc:304: error: ‘KeySym’ was not declared in this scope
x.cc:304: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
x.cc:326: error: ‘Colormap’ was not declared in this scope
x.cc:326: error: expected primary-expression before ‘n_tries’
x.cc:326: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
x.cc:326: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

Can you tell me how to solve the problems?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `.conf.macosx` instead of `configure`;
2. Open `conf.macosx` and add line: `--with-x11`;
3. Run:

   ```
   sh .conf.macosx
   ```
4. Run:

   ```
   make
   ```